# PySpark: Filter condition which multiple columns is in a Dataframe without explicit join

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have a query in `sql` level:

```sql
select user_id,genre from tb
where (user_id,cnt) in (select user_id, max(cnt) from tb group by user_id)
```

which is select the most `genre` of each `user_id` by the `cnt`

Now I want to implement the `where` staement this query in `Dataframe` level to be something like

```py
filter( tb['user_id','cnt'] in tb.groupby('user_id').max('cnt') )
```

that code will throws errors but make me feel more 'readable' in my code. Anyone know the way to make the code in Dataframe level kind of like its sql level?

p/s: I know although my query in `Dataframe` level can be done by `join` and the execution plan is the same but as I said I want to write code in the way that I familiar with

Comment: use a window to calculate the max of `cnt`, and filter the rows where `max_cnt == cnt`